# pandas groupby and get only values when whole column is consistent per group

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame of items with two different ids. id1 and id2, where id2 is truly unique and there can be several id2 to one id1. The item features are specific to the id2s.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[111, 12345, "A", "red", "big"],
                  [111, 12399, "A", "red", "small"],
                  [222, 345, "B", "red", "small"],
                  [222, 349, "B", "blue", "small"]],
                  columns=["id1", "id2", "feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]
```

```
    id1     id2     feature1    feature2    feature3
0   111     12345   A           red         big
1   111     12399   A           red         small
2   222     345     B           red         small
3   222     349     B           blue        small
```

I want to group by id1 and get cponsistent values in the columns, only when all rows in a group have the same value in that column, else a NaN. So the expected result in the above example is :

```
     id2    feature1    feature2    feature3
id1
111  NaN    A           red         NaN
222  NaN    B           NaN         small
```

I've written this function that I want to apply to the grouped object, but it doesn't work this way:

```py
def consistent(series):
    if series.nunique() == 1:
        return series.iloc[0]
    else:
        return np.nan

df1.groupby("id1").apply(consistent)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below:

```
df.groupby("id1").apply(lambda x: x.apply(consistent))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with :

```
import numpy as np
df.groupby("id1").agg(lambda x: np.nan if len(set(x)) != 1 else list(set(x))[0])
```

The output of this code is :

```
id1 id2 feature1    feature2    feature3

111 NaN A   red NaN
222 NaN B   NaN small
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I *like* your answer more, as it is a more succint solution than writing an extra function, but I chose @Ave799 's answer, as it resolved for me how to correctly use .apply() .